# Is Brahmoism Avodah Zarah?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, non-rabbinic-judaism

Sometime during the eighteenth century, [Raja Ram Mohan Roy](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Ram_Mohan_Roy), an educated revenue officer from West Bengal who was influenced by Christianity of the East India Company, founded the "anusthanic" Brahmo Samaj, [a monotheist form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmoism) of Hinduism that worships only one G-d.

In his book "Rabbi on the Ganges," Rabbi Alan Brill summed it up this way:

> **Brahmo Samaj and Ram Mohan Roy**
>
> The Brahmo Samaj was the first of the nineteenth century Hindu reform
> movements, founded in  Kolkata in 1828 by Raja Ram Mohan Roy,
> thereafter resulting in the Brahmo religion in 1805 founded by
> Debendranath Tagore—better known as the father of Rabindranath Tagor.
> They strove toward a modernized, humanistic Hinduism with an eye open
> for societal problems.     Ram Mohan Roy (1772-1833), born into a
> Brahmin family and the recipient of both Hindu and Muslim education
> eventually developed a strong symphony for the Unitarian Christians,
> even writing a work on the messages of Jesus. Roy eventually broke
> with Christianity and developed his Hindu reform movement.     Roy’s
> most famous social reform is to campaign against window burning
> (sati). some of his other reforms included a rejection of Hindu
> pantheism, to be substituted with a more biblical notion of
> anthropomorphic monotheism; rejection of Hindu mythology, rejection of
> all iconic worship of “graven images,” rejection of sacrifices, and a
> repudiation of the doctrine of avataras.
> The Brahmo Samaj movement strove toward monotheism, rejected the worship of forms and idols, and no longer regarded the Vedas or the
> medieval Hindu classics as the sole religious authority. The Brahmo
> Samaj put forth principles that they widely circulated, of not adoring
> any created thing, no graven images and no animate or inanimate
> objects. One served God by performing good deeds, by promoting
> charity, morality, piety, benevolence and virtue, and through
> strengthening the bonds of union between men of all religions and
> creeds.

Is this faith considered Avodah Zarah? It seems as though Roy would hope not, for in his portrait he can be seen holding a Bible.

Comment: @setszu Avraham was not a monotheist but a henotheist. In fact, the Patriarchs, and even the later Israelites (except maybe for Moses) were not monotheists but henotheists. (Look it up)

Comment: You're wrong. As a side note, who is deleting my comments and why? It's starting to seriously irritate me.

Comment: @setszu I don’t know why the comments were deleted. We were having a nice conversation there.

Comment: @setszu Abraham is depicted as a
polytheist who assumes
the existence of many
gods as reflected in the
following Biblical verse
(Genesis 14, 22) in which
Abraham says: "And Abram said to the
king of Sodom: "I have
lifted up my hand unto the Lord (YHVH), God Most High, Maker of heaven and earth."

Comment: This is possibly the worst exegesis of the Biblical text I have ever read.... That verse in fact, affirms total and absolute monotheism, which is also affirmed by other passages...